# What kind of algorithm should I use for this round table problem?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, computer-science

My task is to determine if I can seat N guests on a round table based on their like/dislike on other guests. There are two requirements for seating arrangement:

1. All guests should not be seated next to guests they dislike
2. All guests should be seated to next to guests they like

Input:
likeSet = { guest_id: [list of other guests] },
dislikeSet = { guest_id: [list of other guests] }

Output: Boolean

---

A brute force solution would be starting from seating guest 0 and checking all possible seatings but this is definitely inefficient.

It seems like a variation of the bipartition problem but I am not sure where to start.

Any inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: blindly guess: 1) build (directed?) graph, where vertex - is guest, edge - if guest likes other one. 2) find Hamiltonian cycle

Comment: @user3386109 I think the two requirements are exclusive as favors are not necessarily mutual. For example, if guest A likes guest B but guest B does not guest A, they shouldn't be seated next to each other. Without requirement 1, the result will include the case where A and B are seated next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

As tym32167 pointed out in a comment this problem is similar to the Hamiltonian Cycle problem, which means it is NP-hard and there is unlikely to be a polynomial time solution to it.

For the reduction:

-Suppose we have an efficient solution to the problem at hand. We will use it to solve an instance of HAM-CYCLE, an established NP-hard problem.

-For the input graph G = (V, E), then for each pair of vertices u, v:

1. If (u, v) is in E, u 'likes' v
2. Else, u 'dislikes' v

-Then we use the efficient solution to compute the boolean output: can these guests be seated around the table? If they can, we know that there is an ordering of guests such that each element 'likes' adjacent elements (is connected to them),  such that the last 'likes' the first (a cycle), such that each guest is seated at most once (simple cycle) and that every guest is seated at least once.

-With this knowledge, we can return true or false to the HAM-CYCLE problem, having solved it in polynomial time.